# Javafx gui is not appearing and other everything running fine

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

When I try to run the code everything running fine but GUI is not appearing and also there is no error or any other issue. Even screen also get swapped but then there is no GUI.

I am trying to run this code in Eclipse.

```
  import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class checker extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button bt = new Button("OK");
        Scene sc = new Scene(bt, 250, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me (OS X 10.13.6, JDK jdk1.8.0_162), app displays a window with large OK button.  I don't know why it does not work for you.

Comment: Really? My projects never looked like that. Maybe 'cause I'm on IntelliJ? I usually have something like `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));` `Scene scene = new Scene(root);` `primaryStage.setScene(scene); ` `primaryStage.show();` . Also, check to see if you've this in the FXML file `fx:controller="ProjectName.checker"`

Comment: Works fine for me as well (Windows 10, Java 8u202 and OpenJDK-12/OpenJFX-12). However, I launched from the command line, not Eclipse. Does the problem only occur when using Eclipse?

Comment: @Slaw Yeah, with ecllipse it creates that problem. I don't know how to solve it. And I can't other IDE because my Professor wants me to do on that only.

Comment: No issue here on Windows 10, JDK 8u161, IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 either. I've added the [eclipse] tag to the question since it seems to be isolated to that IDE.

Comment: Sorry - your code works for me pretty much as is (I just put it in a package, rather than leaving it at top level).  I am running Eclipse Oxygen 3a - but I believe I installed e(fx)clipse and scene builder:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-eclipse.htm
That might have modified my Eclipse workspace in such a way as to make it work for me...